# convexity and sufficient decrease condition on quadratic function

Tags: optimization, constrained-optimization, convex-optimization, discrete-optimization

[image]

a) Here how to prove if f is strictly convex function because hessian positive definiteness doesn't imply that f is strictly convex.

[image]

d) Here on picture I have a problem because when gamma is greater than 1/2 I cannot guess if it is greater than 1/2 because there is s^TCs which is greater than 0 but it can be also between 0 and 1 and (1-gama)*s^TCs is not greater or equal to 1/2

Comment: [Partial duplicate](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/44030/convexity-on-quadratic-function).